# Impact of numerous indexes on query optimizer for a delete statement

Tags: optimization, execution-plan, delete, postgresql-9.5

We have a 10GB table with 30GB indexes on it. The table consists of a few dozens of attributes a primary key on the `id` (`varchar(32)` type) and a dozen of indexes on anything but `id` key (except the default primary key index). The primary index is

```
create table tbl (
  id character varying(36) NOT NULL,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT pk_repavo PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I also added additional few indexes:

```
create index pk_repavo2 on tbl (id) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80);
create index pk_repavo3 on tbl ((id::text)) WITH (FILLFACTOR=80);
```

Deleting a record results in a sequential scan always:

```
explain DELETE FROM tbl WHERE ID = 'fd1f6fa5-7cd2-4c08-a702-86dae9bad5ab'

Delete on tbl  (cost=0.00..1638100.65 rows=1 width=6)
  ->  Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..1638100.65 rows=1 width=6)
        Filter: ((id)::text = 'fd1f6fa5-7cd2-4c08-a702-86dae9bad5ab'::text)
```

If I do

```
set enable_seqscan=off;
```

The plan turns into

```
Delete on tbl  (cost=10000000000.00..10001638100.65 rows=1 width=6)"
  ->  Seq Scan on tbl (cost=10000000000.00..10001638100.65 rows=1 width=6)
        Filter: ((id)::text = 'fd1f6fa5-7cd2-4c08-a702-86dae9bad5ab'::text)
```

Is it because of those 30GB of indexes that are not related to `id`?

I did `vacuum` and `analyze` on the table.

Query

```
select *
from pg_settings 
where name like '%cost%'
```

returns

```
"autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay";"20"
"autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit";"-1"
"cpu_index_tuple_cost";"0.005"
"cpu_operator_cost";"0.0025"
"cpu_tuple_cost";"0.01"
"random_page_cost";"4"
"seq_page_cost";"1"
"vacuum_cost_delay";"0"
"vacuum_cost_limit";"200"
"vacuum_cost_page_dirty";"20"
"vacuum_cost_page_hit";"1"
"vacuum_cost_page_miss";"10"
```

Query

```
select *
from pg_settings 
where name like '%enable_%'
```

returns

```
"enable_bitmapscan";"on"
"enable_hashagg";"on"
"enable_hashjoin";"on"
"enable_indexonlyscan";"on"
"enable_indexscan";"on"
"enable_material";"on"
"enable_mergejoin";"on"
"enable_nestloop";"on"
"enable_seqscan";"off"
"enable_sort";"on"
"enable_tidscan";"on"
```

Query

```
select row_to_json(pg_stat_all_tables) from pg_stat_all_tables
where relname like '%tbl%'
```

returns

```
{
    "relid":"18599",
    "schemaname":"x",
    "relname":"tbl",
    "seq_scan":79610,
    "seq_tup_read":1962006021668,
    "idx_scan":3608071,
    "idx_tup_fetch":471460457,
    "n_tup_ins":24709321,
    "n_tup_upd":16838,
    "n_tup_del":74794,
    "n_tup_hot_upd":351,
    "n_live_tup":24687261,
    "n_dead_tup":12233,
    "n_mod_since_analyze":3682,
    "last_vacuum":"2018-05-16T12:32:17.094383+02:00",
    "last_autovacuum":null,
    "last_analyze":"2018-05-16T12:32:25.478913+02:00",
    "last_autoanalyze":"2018-05-12T12:26:37.226609+02:00",
    "vacuum_count":1,
    "autovacuum_count":0,
    "analyze_count":3,
    "autoanalyze_count":1
}
```

Is there any way to get the cost of query using an index? Using all generated query plans by query optimizer? Why doesn't delete use an index? Is it because there are another a dozen of indexes that are not built on id?

We have postgres version 9.5.1 (we know it is outdated).

Additional Infos:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
  id character varying(36) NOT NULL,
  a2 timestamp without time zone,
  a3 boolean,
  a4 character varying(255),
  a5 timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  a6 boolean,
  a7 timestamp without time zone,
  a8 timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  a9 character varying(255),
  a10 boolean,
  a11 timestamp without time zone,
  a12 character varying(255),
  a13 character varying(36) NOT NULL,
  a14 timestamp without time zone,
  a15 boolean,
  a16 character varying(36),
  a17 character varying(36),
  a18 character varying(255),
  a19 timestamp without time zone,
  a20 character varying(255),
  a21 character varying(255),
  a22 character varying(255),
  a23 character varying(255),
  a24 character varying(255),
  a25 character varying(2000),
  a26 timestamp without time zone,
  a27 boolean,
  a28 character varying(255),
  a29 bigint,
  a30 character varying(255),
  a31 boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  a32 character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNKNOWN'::character varying,
  CONSTRAINT pk_repavo PRIMARY KEY (id)  WITH (FILLFACTOR=80)
)


CREATE INDEX if1
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a16 COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX inx2
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a21 COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX ix3
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a20 COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX ix4
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a17 COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX ix5
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a16 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a13 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a29);


CREATE INDEX ix6
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a22 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a23 COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX ix7
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a22 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a6, a23 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a25 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a10);

CREATE INDEX ix8
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a22 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a21 COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX ix9
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a16 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a19)
  WITH (FILLFACTOR=80);

CREATE INDEX ix10
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a16 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a13 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a6);

CREATE INDEX ix11
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a16 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a13 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a15);

CREATE INDEX ix12
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a22 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a20 COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX ix13
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a22 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a17 COLLATE pg_catalog."default");


CREATE INDEX ix14
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (a22 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a10, a23 COLLATE pg_catalog."default", a25 COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX pk_repavo2
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  ((id::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
  WITH (FILLFACTOR=80);

CREATE INDEX pk_repavo3
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (id COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
  WITH (FILLFACTOR=80);
```

Comment: Could someone have disabled the index on pk_repavo?

Comment: well, I just created it.. But that's an interesting idea

Comment: what is the use of ((id)::text) if id is a varchar?   What do you mean you just created the index on id?  Postgresql should have created it when the table was created.

Comment: pg_index reports that `indisvalid, indislive, indisready, indimmediate,` are all true. @GerardH.Pille: it is true that postgres creates indexes when the table is created, we added the PK constraint later (we recreated the constrains after we maintained the table). Whats the use of `id::text`? it shows how desperate I am, and willing to try even the most banal cases.

Comment: I'd love to see the explain if you drop all indices on the id column, apart from the primary key index.  BTW, what's its name?

Comment: Care to add output from a "\d tbl" to your question?

Comment: Has "id" always been "varchar(36)" ?

Comment: the `id` was always `varchar(36)`

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: The explain is the same independent whether there's an additional index on `id` or not.

Comment: I find that hard to believe.  "((id)::text = 'fd1f6fa5-7cd2-4c08-a702-86dae9bad5ab'::text)" when there is no index on (id)::text ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: forgot to "refresh" the table. Additional two indexes appeared. The third index (`pk_repavo`) is not shown as this is a primary key

Comment: Why are you using `varchar(36)` instead of `uuid`? This would save 20 bytes of storage per row.

Comment: Does Postgresql recognize 'fd1f6fa5-7cd2-4c08-a702-86dae9bad5ab' as being a UUID?

Comment: @Colin'tHart: because it is the old version of our software. the new one uses `uuid`. The customer did not want to upgrade. The string `fd...ab' is a string in this version (so no, it does not recognize, and it is not supposed to)

Comment: I've asked for a "\d tbl" to see the indexes.  Do you have a unique index on tbl.id?